# How to access the nested html which is within a frame through Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a website where a html tag is nested inside like below. 
Questions:

1. How to search for element in frameBody using selenium?
2. How to wait for element in frameBody successful loaded?

Please help. Thanks. 
Please get the application source code from this [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dAQa6ml4UqCkCUJyTlaRDpBLdYGltRW-).

[image]

Comment: I tried with this driver.switchTo().frame("frameBody"); but it causes No frame element found by name or id frameBody.

Answer (score 1):

The `<frame>` with `id = frameBody` is nested in another `<iframe>`, you need to switch to it first

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tabFrames > iframe:nth-child(1)"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
driver.switchTo().frame("frameBody");
```

Comment: Please see my screenshot of code. Can you pin point me the exact structure?

Comment: @peterwkc The structure is very clear, you can see it by the indentations. You can also open and close sections in the developer tools to see it.

Comment: It throws NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: tabFrames > iframe:nth-child(2)

Comment: @peterwkc It should be `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#tabFrames > iframe:nth-child(1)"));`

Comment: I"m using xpath and it works.